# Laplace transform asymptotic for $x \to -\infty$

Tags: asymptotics, laplace-transform

The Laplace transform $\int_0^\infty e^{-tx} f(t) dt$ is for large $x$ asymptotically equivalent to $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{x^{n+1}}$ (Watson's lemma).

Given that the Laplace transform converges everywhere, is there a similar formula for $x \to -\infty$?

Comment: You meant $f$ is smooth and $O(e^{rx})$ then $\int_0^\infty e^{-tx} f(t) dt=\sum_{n=0}^N \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{x^{n+1}}+O(1/x^{N+2})$.  For $x\to -\infty$, yes if $f$ is supported on $[0,a]$, otherwise no.

Comment: What do you mean by otherwise no? For example $f(t) = 1/(t^t+1)$ is not compactly supported, but it's Laplace transform should converge everywhere. Therefore it should be asymptotically equal to something.

Comment: There is no formula giving a simple asymptotic

Comment: Do you know how to obtain an asymptotic? If there is no general formula, is there any kind of procedure or something like that?

Comment: In most cases no. It can grow arbitrary fast and there is no sequence of elementary function growing faster than every function.